# Convert part of Formula from Relative to Absolute Reference

Tags: excel, vba, reference

Originally I wanted to change parts of a formula in every 82th row where the formula looks like

```
=SUMIFS($BJ:$BJ;$BO:$BO;$BI7382;$A:$A;"<="&$A7382;A:A;">"&A7383)
```

So I wanted to change each formula for a thousand of rows from `(...;$BI7382;...;"<="&$A7382;...)` to:
`(...;$BI$7382;...;"<="&$A$7382;...)` where `$7382` is always one row before the row that includes the formula above. 
So the next row with this formula would be $7464 where my code should change from `(...;$BI7463;...;"<="&$A7463;...)` to:
`(...;$BI$7463;...;"<="&$A$7463;...)` and so on.

I had success with your code

```
For i = 7383 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 82
Cells(i, 1).Formula = Replace(Cells(i, 1).Formula, "$BI" & i - 1, "$BI$" & i - 1)
Cells(i, 1).Formula = Replace(Cells(i, 1).Formula, "$A" & i - 1, "$A$" & i - 1)
```

But: There is a single column which has cells with

```
=SUMIFS($BJ:$BJ;$BO:$BO;$BI7382;$A:$A;<="&$A7382;A:A;">"&$A7383)
```

where the last value has changed from

```
">"&A7383to">"&$A7383
```

such that the last two values both have absolute column references

Because the code finds two values with $A... the replace function does not work properly 
(Cells look like `=SUMIFS($BJ:$BJ;$BO:$BO;$BI7382;$A:$A;"<="&$A7382;A:A;">"&` after the code is executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the string `"SUMIFS($BI" & cl.Row - 1` does not exist in your formula, so nothing gets replaced. Try the following line, it should work.

```
cl.Formula = Replace(cl.Formula, "$BI" & cl.Row - 1, "$BI$" & cl.Row - 1)
```

Now, it is better to declare the variable `i` as an `Integer` since it is used as a row index, and row indexes are integers. That way we avoid inaccuracy of `Double` (i.e. floating-point) arithmetic.

```
Dim i As Integer
```

In the `For` loop, `i` starts at `7383` and is incremented by steps of `81`. This is good. However, `i` is not used anywhere in the replace statement. But the `For Each` loops through all rows of column `O`. The `For Each` is not needed. You can access cells in column `O` with `Cells(i, 15)`. So the `For` loop becomes:

```
For i = 7383 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 81
    Cells(i, 15).Formula = Replace(Cells(i, 15).Formula, "$BI" & i - 1, "$BI$" & i - 1)
Next i
```

The upper bound value of `i` in the `For` loop is determined by the contents of column `A`. If column `A` has fewer rows than column `O`, then some replacements may be missed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately VBA always shows an error while trying to compile. First a message appeared showing that my variable rng is not defined, after trying some things I now get the message in line

Set rng = Range("O:O")

that the types are not compatible. Anyway I am not able to get any results?

Comment: Of course: `Sub AbsoluterBezug()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim i As Double

Set rng = ("O:O")
For i = 7383 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 81
For Each cl In rng
    cl.Formula = Replace(cl.Formula, "$BI" & cl.Row - 1, "$BI$" & cl.Row - 1)
Next cl
Next i

End Sub`

Comment: Just saw one problem that I did not see initially. I will update my answer.

Comment: So you suggesting the following code? `Sub AbsoluteRef()
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 7384 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 81
    Cells(i, 15).Formula = Replace(Cells(i, 15).Formula, "SUMIFS($BI" & i - 1, "SUMIFS($BI$" & i - 1)

Next i
End Sub` Unfortunately nothing happens at all alt

Comment: Sorry! Just saw the "SUMIF". I will correct it. It was too early this morning when I updated it :-) Note that `15` is for column `O`.

Comment: Of course, I should have figured it out myself. Now it works just fine. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Unfortunately there is a problem in a single column now because in this column the formula looks like =SUMIFS($BJ:$BJ;$BO:$BO;$BI7382;$A:$A;"<="&$A7382;A:A;">"&$A7383). So the last column value is an absolute reference instead of a relative value. Thus the macro is not working as it cuts off the last value. I have already tried to replace the whole row but my code is not working at all..

Comment: @blowbuh - I do not understand. I suggest that you edit the question,  **add** your new code, and explain what is still not working.

Comment: Actually my question addressed Cells with formula `=SUMIFS($BJ:$BJ;$BO:$BO;$BI7382;$A:$A;"<="&$A7382;A:A;">"&A7383)` but there is a single column which has cells with `=SUMIFS($BJ:$BJ;$BO:$BO;$BI7382;$A:$A;<="&$A7382;A:A;">"&$A7383)`where the last value has changed from `">"&A7383`to`">"&$A7383`such that the last two values both have absolute column references.

Comment: The code is `Sub AbsoluteRef()
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 7383 To Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Row Step 82
    Cells(i, 19).Formula = Replace(Cells(i, 19).Formula, "$BI" & i - 1, "$BI$" & i - 1)
    Cells(i, 19).Formula = Replace(Cells(i, 19).Formula, "$A" & i - 1, "$A$" & i - 1)

Next i
End Sub` Because the code finds two values with `$A...` the replace function does not work properly (Cells look like `=SUMIFS($BJ:$BJ;$BO:$BO;$BI7382;$A:$A;"<="&$A7382;A:A;">"&`)

Comment: @blowbuh - Code in comments is very difficult to read. You can edit your original question and add new info to it. Or, if this might be a new problem, then you should post a new question.

Comment: Sorry I have to get used to this platform. However I have edited my original post.

Comment: @blowbuh - If the last value changed, it means the value of `i` is wrong. That is, `i = 7384` instead of `7383`. I noticed that step used to be `81` and now it is `82`. Is that correct?

Comment: First, step 82 is correct but that's not the problem. I am not sure if you got me right. Originally I wanted to change cells with formula =SUMIFS(...;">"&A7383) but one column has cells with formula =SUMIFS(...;">"&$A7383). As the code suggests replacing "$A" with "$A$" does not work since there are now two "$A". But I only want to change the "$A7382" to "$A$7382"; I don't want to change the last value "$A7383" - it should stay as it is, with a relative row reference

Comment: @blowbuh - The code does not replace `"$A"` with `"$A$"` but `"$A" & i - 1` with `"$A$" & i - 1`. If `i = 7384`, then code replaces `"$A7383"` with `"$A$7383"`. That is the only way the last value could have changed, i.e. `i = 7384`.

Comment: @blowbuh Does my last comment make sense?

Comment: @blowbuh I know you are new to this site, but I answered the original question, you accepted it, and then you tried to apply the solution to something else that was not in the original question, and you unaccepted the answer! This is unfair :-( You should have asked another question for the second problem. It was impossible for me to propose a solution that would have worked for a case that you did not show originally. Right?

Comment: I am really sorry, I intuitively thought it might be better to continue this discussion since you are involved and it is not far from the original issue but I was not able to express myself properly that's why it probably got chaotic. But now I know better. It was only one column which I handled manually. Thank you!

Comment: @blowbuh The idea of this site is to build a set of questions with their answers so that in the future people having a problem similar to this one can find an answer. So, questions have to be specific to be useful, and the good answers are determined by people voting for them.